# Binding data in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-binding, data-visualization

In this code: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208

What is the function of the third (data) in

```
.data(stack.keys(data.columns.slice(1))(data))
```

Answer (score 3):

This line can be better understood if we break it and create some new variables to show what's happening.

First, we define the stack generator with the keys accessor:

```
var stack = d3.stack()
    .keys(data.columns.slice(1));
```

Then, we stack the data (the `data` here corresponds to the `data` in your question, which is the data being stacked):

```
var stackedData = stack(data)
//data being stacked-----^
```

And we finally bind the data:

```
g.selectAll(".serie")
    .data(stackedData);
```

Thus, what you called the *third* data is simply the data that will be stacked. The problem is, in Bostock's code, instead of defining the keys accessor in the stack generator variable, like I did, and defining the stacked data as a new variable...

```
var stack = d3.stack()
    .keys(data.columns.slice(1));
var stackedData = stack(data);
```

... he's doing everything in a single step, inside the `data()` function, which has the same effect:

```
.data(stack.keys(data.columns.slice(1))(data))
//           ^---keys accessor           ^----data being stacked
```

Comment: thank you. i'm probably an intermediate coder at this point, and some of this d3 stuff looks like black magic to me. this is the first time i've seen a function and a variable next to each other without a comma, is this a common occurrence?

Comment: Sorry, but where are you seeing a function and a variable next to each other?

Comment: .data(stack.keys(data.columns.slice(1))    *no comma*    (data))

Comment: There should be no comma: `data` is the argument of the function.

Comment: which `data`? (bostock really needs to stop using shorthand for bl.ocks.org examples...)

Comment: The third `data` is just the argument of the stack function (between parenthesis), and the stack function is the argument of the `data` function. So, you have a `data` function and a `data` variable in this code.

Comment: i guess the part i don't understand is how 

`stack.keys(data.columns.slice(1)) (data)`

can be a single argument

Comment: It is a single argument, and it is itself a function with an argument inside it.